# Null Exception thrown in dropdownlist selected value inside gridview on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, datagridview

Dropdownlist is binds to gridview dynamically.And it will  always in first row of gridview.
When i try to get dropdownlist value its giving null value:

```
Here is code to bind dropdownlist to gridview:

protected void dgData_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    ArrayList strHead = null;
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        strHead = new ArrayList();
        foreach (DataControlFieldCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            strHead.Add(cell.Text);
        }
        ViewState["HeaderCell"] = strHead;
    }
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DropDownList ddl;


        if (e.Row.RowIndex == 0)
        {
            for (Int32 i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                ddl = new DropDownList();
                ddl.ID = "ddlCol" + i.ToString();
                e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(ddl);
                ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(string.Empty, string.Empty));
                ddl.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("First Name", "1"));
                ddl.Items.Insert(2, new ListItem("Last Name", "2"));
                ddl.Items.Insert(3, new ListItem("Company Name", "3"));
                ddl.Items.Insert(4, new ListItem("Account No", "4"));
                ddl.Items.Insert(5, new ListItem("Account No 2", "5"));
                ddl.Items.Insert(6, new ListItem("Account No 3", "6"));
                ddl.Items.Insert(7, new ListItem("Groups", "7"));
                ddl.Items.Insert(8, new ListItem("Business Phone", "8"));
                ddl.Items.Insert(9, new ListItem("Home Phone", "9"));
                ddl.Items.Insert(10, new ListItem("Mobile", "10"));
                ddl.Items.Insert(11, new ListItem("Email", "11"));
                ddl.Items.Insert(12, new ListItem("Other Phone Number", "12"));
                ddl.Items.Insert(13, new ListItem("Web Page", "13"));
                ddl.Items.Insert(14, new ListItem("IM Address", "14"));
                ddl.Items.Insert(15, new ListItem("Comment", "15"));
                ddl.Items.Insert(16, new ListItem("Street Address 1", "16"));
                ddl.Items.Insert(17, new ListItem("Street Address 2", "17"));
                ddl.Items.Insert(18, new ListItem("Street City / Suburb", "18"));
                ddl.Items.Insert(19, new ListItem("Street State", "19"));
                ddl.Items.Insert(20, new ListItem("Street Post Code", "20"));
                ddl.Items.Insert(21, new ListItem("Street Country", "21"));
                ddl.Items.Insert(22, new ListItem("Mailing Address 1", "22"));
                ddl.Items.Insert(23, new ListItem("Mailing Address 2", "23"));
                ddl.Items.Insert(24, new ListItem("Mailing City / Suburb", "24"));
                ddl.Items.Insert(25, new ListItem("Mailing State", "25"));
                ddl.Items.Insert(26, new ListItem("Mailing Post Code", "26"));
                ddl.Items.Insert(27, new ListItem("Mailing Country", "27"));
                ddl.Items.Insert(28, new ListItem("Notes", "28"));
                ddl.Items.Insert(29, new ListItem("Custom Fields", "29"));
                ddl.Items.Insert(30, new ListItem("Relationship Manager", "30"));
                ddl.Items.Insert(31, new ListItem("Primary Interest", "31"));
                ddl.Items.Insert(32, new ListItem("Account Manager", "32"));
                strHead = (ArrayList)ViewState["HeaderCell"];




                foreach(ListItem item in ddl.Items)
        {
             if (strHead[i].ToString() == item.Text)
             {
            ddl.SelectedValue = item.Value;
             }
            else
             {
         // ddl.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }


                }

            }



         }

    }

  }
```

code to bind gridview:

```
 private void grdbind()
{


    DataTable db = new DataTable();
    db = (DataTable)Session["csvdata"];
    DataRow newrow = db.NewRow();
    db.Rows.InsertAt(newrow, 0);

    colcount = db.Columns.Count;

    dgData.DataSource = db;
    dgData.DataBind();


  }
```

Here is the code to fetch dropdownlist value on button click where i am getting problem:

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     GridViewRow row;
    row = dgData.Rows[0];
   DropDownList ddl= (DropDownList)(row.Cells[1].FindControl("ddlCol1"));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a header row, it will always be at the index 0, so you can't test for it not being the header row and having an index of 0, as both checks will return false.

Change your index in both your check for adding the DDL, and the code to fetch it.

Adding code:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    DropDownList ddl;

    if (e.Row.RowIndex == 1)
    {
        // ..... 
    }
}
```

Fetching code:

```
GridViewRow row = dgData.Rows[1];
DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)row.Cells[1].FindControl("ddlCol1");
```