# how to get dropdown value inside gridview on button click in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

I have tried this but its not working,giving null value:please tell me what have to change in this code.

```
      protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 GridViewRow row;
row = dgData.Rows[0];
DropDownList ddl= (DropDownList)(row.Cells[1].FindControl("ddlCol1"));

}
```

Comment: are u using `update panel` or not

Comment: no dropdownlist added to gridview  dynamically

Comment: show me your `page_load` as well or are you using `Page.Ispostback` on `page_load` or not

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
        {
           grdbind();
        }

    }

Comment: you can see full code here  :   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891245/null-exception-thrown-in-dropdownlist-selected-value-inside-gridview-on-button-c

Comment: instead of `dropdownlist` try to find another control like `textbox` oe `label` and check is it showing null as well or not.

Answer (score 0):

use

> DropDownList ddl= (DropDownList)(row.FindControl("ddlCol1"));

and try and let me know

Comment: not working still giving null......you can see  full code here:        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891245/null-exception-thrown-in-dropdownlist-selected-value-inside-gridview-on-button-c

Comment: yes and on button click i want to fetch its value to save in database but i am getting null

Comment: try this
DropDownList ddl= (DropDownList)(row.Cells[1].Controls.OfType<DropDownList>().FirstOrDefault())

Answer (score 0):

try this code on click event

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        //Finding Dropdown control  
        DropDownList ddl1 = row.FindControl("ddlTest") as DropDownList;
        if (ddl1 != null)
        {
           // your code here  
        }
    }
```

Comment: please post your grid view syntax and code for binding that grid view

Comment: Hi Aijaz you see whole code here::  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891245/null-exception-thrown-in-dropdownlist-selected-value-inside-gridview-on-button-c/16893369?noredirect=1#16893369

Answer (score 0):

@creby i saw your code.

you are adding your dropdown in grid view during row data bound event ok.. but now when you click on the button, all the drop down will be vanished so that's why you will not able to get drop down.

use item template of grid view and then bind dropdown in row data bound event.

Comment: yes you are right,but i have to add dropdown dynamically in gridview...what is happening here is data coming from csv file.i have save this data in session,on this page i have bind the gridview with session value.but before adding session value i have added empty row at first position and on first row i have added dynamicalyy dropdown because i want dropdown at first row with same values as i have added in my code..please help

Comment: is your dropdown is in empty row , that you enterd at first?

Comment: yes you can see i add empty row at 0 index...and in row databound at 0 index i add sropdownlist  ...see code :   DataTable db = new DataTable();
        db = (DataTable)Session["csvdata"];
        DataRow newrow = db.NewRow();
        db.Rows.InsertAt(newrow, 0);
          dgData.DataSource = db;
        dgData.DataBind();